# lubuntu presentation cuts right side

Tags: permissions, presentation

i am using lubuntu but when i connect my laptop with projector my screen cuts right side of the presentation. What could be the reason. Can someone help to resolve this.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have same experience like you. I solved it by self, with sync the resolution on my laptop with resolution of the projector .When you already connected with your projector open monitor settings in menu or open terminal and type this command :

> **lxrandr**

set your vga resolution to 800x600 and the dvi resolution 800x600 , then press apply .

Good luck .